# Infer Type when Extending Generic Class

Tags: typescript, class, generics

Currently what I want to achieve is inferring a generic type (T) when extending a class (which has T as generic parameter). So, something like this:

```js
class A<T> {
  val;
  constructor(opts: { innerVal: T }) {
    this.val = opts.innerVal;
  }

  func(arg: T) {
    // Some stuff...
  }
}

// new A({ innerVal: { args: { reason: 'Some string' } } })
// Here, T would be automatically inferred as "{ args: { reason: string } }".
// But my goal is to achieve this, but extending the class. Ex:

class B extends A { // Generic should be inferred automatically, but TypeScript yells at you for doing this.
  constructor() {
    super({ innerVal: { args: { reason: 'Some string' } });
  }

  // Here I would define a function with an arg (SuperClassGenericType) which's type is the same as the super class generic type, in this case "{ args: { reason: string } }".
  otherFunc(arg: SuperClassGenericType) {}
}
```

Any ideas about how I can achieve this behavior would be incredible :). Thanks.

Comment: Consider using class `B<T = X>` and make X be the inferred type.

Comment: Your example might be too far from actual use. In this case you'd just use `class B extends A<{ args: { reason: 'Some string' } }> {`. _SuperClassGenericType_ isn't actually generic at all. It's given by the constructor. Shouldn't there be some parameter for the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generic should be inferred automatically, but TypeScript yells at you for doing this.
> This is not true. In your case, class `A` expects explicit generic parameter.

Please keep in mind, if you want just create instance of `class A` it is not mandatory to provide a generic. This code is perfectly valid:

```js
const x = new A({ innerVal: 42 })
```

`T` infered as a number.

But when you extends your `B` class with `A`, TS is unable to infer `T` parameter and requires it explicitly.

Also, TypeScript is unable bind infered type of `T` from `super` arguments:

```js
 super({ innerVal: { args: { reason: 'string' } } });
```

with `A` in class declaration.

You have two possible solutions.

**First one**, you can define type of `super` argument upfront:

```js
class A<T> {
  val;
  constructor(opts: { innerVal: T }) {
    this.val = opts.innerVal;
  }

  func(arg: T) {
    // Some stuff...
  }
}

type Data={ args: { reason: 'string' } };

class B extends A<Data> { 
  constructor() {
    super({ innerVal: { args: { reason: 'string' } } });
  }

  otherFunc(arg: this['val']) { }
}

const y = new B();
y.otherFunc() // expected Data argument
```

**Second solution**
You can create factory function:

```js
class A<T> {
  val;
  constructor(opts: { innerVal: T }) {
    this.val = opts.innerVal;
  }

  func(arg: T) {
    // Some stuff...
  }
}

type Data = { args: { reason: 'string' } };



const factory = <T,>(data: T) =>
  class B extends A<T> {
    constructor() {
      super({ innerVal: data });
    }

    otherFunc(arg: this['val']) { }
  }

const Clazz = factory({ age: 42 })
const result = new Clazz()

result.otherFunc() // expected argument is { age: number; }
```